# How to sum a multiple count from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sum

Hope someone can help me with..

For my **Loyalty Program** I count the amount of songs being added, amount of lessons being addes, amount of comments on lesson and songs and more.

For a **hall of fame** I would like to make a view of members with the **highest reputation**. and also add the reputation underneat the avatar.

Therefor I would like to sum: 
TOTAL = totalsongs + totallesson + totalsongcomments + totallessoncomments

My tables look like:

Poster

```
poster_id| username | 
---------|----------|
1        | lisa
2        | john
3        | ben
```

Lesson

```
lesson_id| title    | poster_id
---------|----------|----------
1        | lesson1  | 1
2        | lesson2  | 1
3        | lesson3  | 2
4        | lesson4  | 3
5        | lesson5  | 1
6        | lesson7  | 2
```

Song

```
song_id  | title    | poster_id
---------|----------|----------
1        | song 1   | 1
2        | song 2   | 1
3        | song 3   | 2
```

SongComment

```
com_id   | song_id  | poster_id | comment
---------|----------|-----------|--------
1        | 1        | 1         | This comment1
2        | 2        | 1         | This comment2
3        | 3        | 2         | This comment3
```

LessonComment

```
com_id   | lesson_id| poster_id | comment
---------|----------|-----------|--------
1        | 1        | 1         | This comment1
2        | 2        | 1         | This comment2
3        | 3        | 2         | This comment3
```

Please help to set up the mysql query

```
    SELECT poster.gebruikersnaam 
    SUM(
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM song) AS totalsongs +
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lesson AS totallesson + 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM songcomment AS totalsongcomments +
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lessoncomment AS totallessoncomments +
        )
    FROM song
    INNER JOIN poster ON poster.poster_id = song.song_poster_id
    WHERE song.song_poster_id !=  '0'
    GROUP BY poster.poster_id
    ORDER BY TOTAL
    LIMIT 0 , 250
```

THIS IS OKE BUT.. still has to order by the sum :)

```
SELECT P.poster_id,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM song WHERE P.poster_id = song.song_poster_id) AS SongCount,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lesson WHERE P.poster_id = lesson.lesson_poster_id) AS LessonCount,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM commentaar WHERE P.poster_id = commentaar.poster_id) AS SongCommCount,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lesson_comment WHERE P.poster_id = lesson_comment.lesson_comment_poster_id) AS LessonCommCount
FROM poster AS P
LIMIT 0, 50
```

EDIT 2

```
    SELECT PM.poster_id , PM.SongCount , PM.LessonCount, PM.SongCommCount, PM.LessonCommCount, (PM.SongCount + PM.LessonCount + PM.SongCommCount + PM.LessonCommCount) AS TotalCount 
FROM (
  SELECT P.poster_id, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM song WHERE P.poster_id = song.song_poster_id) AS SongCount, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lesson WHERE P.poster_id = lesson.lesson_poster_id) AS LessonCount, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM commentaar WHERE P.poster_id = commentaar.poster_id) AS SongCommCount, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lesson_comment WHERE P.poster_id = lesson_comment.lesson_comment_poster_id) AS LessonCommCount 
  FROM poster AS P 
  LIMIT 0, 50
) AS PM
ORDER BY (PM.SongCount + PM.LessonCount + PM.SongCommCount + PM.LessonCommCount) DESC
```

EDIT 3

```
    SELECT poster_id, 
       songCount, lessonCount, songCommentCount, lessonCommentCount,
       songCount + lessonCount + songCommentCount + lessonCommentCount as totalRank
FROM(SELECT poster.poster_id, 
            COALESCE(song.count, 0) as songCount,
            COALESCE(lesson.count, 0) as lessonCount,
            COALESCE(commentaar.count, 0) as songCommentCount,
            COALESCE(lesson_comment.count, 0) as lessonCommentCount
     FROM poster
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT song_poster_id, COUNT(*) as count
                FROM song
                GROUP BY song_poster_id) song
            ON song.song_poster_id = poster.poster_id  
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT lesson_poster_id, COUNT(*) as count
                FROM lesson
                GROUP BY lesson_poster_id) lesson
            ON lesson.lesson_poster_id = poster.poster_id
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT poster_id, COUNT(*) as count
                FROM commentaar
                GROUP BY poster_id) commentaar
            ON commentaar.poster_id = poster.poster_id
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT lesson_comment_poster_id, COUNT(*) as count
                FROM lesson_comment
                GROUP BY lesson_comment_poster_id) lesson_comment
            ON lesson_comment.lesson_comment_poster_id = poster.poster_id) Total
ORDER BY totalRank DESC
LIMIT 0, 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b37a7/1/0) showing that the below query does indeed work.  As you can see, I am creating the tables and populating them with the data you have in your question.  Then I am executing the below query to gather the data you need.  I did verify the counts and they are calculating correctly.

```
SELECT PM.*, 
  (
    PM.SongCount + PM.LessonCount + 
    PM.SongCommCount + PM.LessonCommCount
  ) AS TotalCount 
FROM (
  SELECT P.poster_id, 
    (
      SELECT COUNT(poster_id) 
      FROM song S 
      WHERE P.poster_id = S.poster_id
    ) AS SongCount, 
    (
      SELECT COUNT(poster_id) 
      FROM lesson L 
      WHERE P.poster_id = L.poster_id
    ) AS LessonCount, 
    (
      SELECT COUNT(poster_id) 
      FROM SongComment SC 
      WHERE P.poster_id = SC.poster_id
    ) AS SongCommCount, 
    (
      SELECT COUNT(poster_id) 
      FROM LessonComment LC 
      WHERE P.poster_id = LC.poster_id
    ) AS LessonCommCount 
  FROM poster AS P 
  LIMIT 0, 50
) AS PM
ORDER BY 
  (
    PM.SongCount + PM.LessonCount + 
    PM.SongCommCount + PM.LessonCommCount
  ) DESC
```

Comment: I added LIMIT 0,50 but this query takes: 273.4195 sec to run!? Also it returns 0 for all TotalCounts at the users. Hope you know what goes wrong?

Comment: try the Count() sub queries individually and see if you get a value other than 0

Comment: is this query not strange because i look for the top 50 best posters. But with this is says WHERE P.poster_id = song.poster_id must this not be P.poster_id ON song.poster_id

Comment: No, it is fine.  You have to link the sub query to the main query.  You do so with the WHERE statement.

Comment: Try the edit I added to see if it will run any faster and produce any results.

Comment: I also updated the query and thats oke i do get the amount of the sup counts. But now how to implement the SUM ( .... ) ??

Comment: **@Gitaartabs** Ok, try **Edit 2** and see how that runs

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') FROM song WHERE P.poster_id = song.song_poster_id) AS SongCount,
    (SELECT' at line 4

Comment: this is farmost the complex query i have ever seen :)

Comment: Not working as expected, gives 11 ansers with values but the rest are all 0 ? strange, perhaps we should also display the subvalues

Comment: I added also the count in to display (check my edit 2) but it is not as expected. most values are 0

Comment: See my updated answer for a working version of the query in SQL Fiddle

Comment: It does work but, still some strange 0 values. Perhaps i can make a easy export from my tables into fiddler? (any easy query for that :) ?

Comment: see my edit 4 for the result on this query. (but we have more than 5000 songs and 400 lesson so the result must be wrong

Comment: Your issue probably has something to do with the LIMIT clause.  Try the following [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b37a7/12/0).  if that doesn't help play with the limit a bit. Take the limit off and run it to verify that the query works correctly in your environment.

Comment: it looks like it is working but when i remove the LIMIT it takes extreem long to load, until ... (already waiting 8 minutes.. ?)

Answer (score 0):

Other than @Linger's answer, here's the other usual way to do this:

```
SELECT poster_id, 
       songCount, lessonCount, songCommentCount, lessonCommentCount,
       songCount + lessonCount + songCommentCount + lessonCommentCount as totalRank
FROM(SELECT Poster.poster_id, 
            COALESCE(Song.count, 0) as songCount,
            COALESCE(Lesson.count, 0) as lessonCount,
            COALESCE(SongComment.count, 0) as songCommentCount,
            COALESCE(LessonComment.count, 0) as lessonCommentCount
     FROM Poster
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT poster_id, COUNT(*) as count
                FROM Song
                GROUP BY poster_id) Song
            ON Song.poster_id = Poster.poster_id  
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT poster_id, COUNT(*) as count
                FROM Lesson
                GROUP BY poster_id) Lesson
            ON Lesson.poster_id = Poster.poster_id
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT poster_id, COUNT(*) as count
                FROM SongComment
                GROUP BY poster_id) SongComment
            ON SongComment.poster_id = Poster.poster_id
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT poster_id, COUNT(*) as count
                FROM LessonComment
                GROUP BY poster_id) LessonComment
            ON LessonComment.poster_id = Poster.poster_id) Total
ORDER BY totalRank DESC
LIMIT 0, 50
```

(have a working [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b37a7/10) - thanks to @Linger for the setup)
I don't know enough about mySQL to know if this will be more performant for your situation.  Note that the `LIMIT` clause shouldn't be a problem, given that you want them ordered anyways.  Also, if you don't have indices over `poster_id` in each of the 'child' tables, you're probably going to want them...

Comment: the query does works as expected but:  Query execute time 25.2329 sec. But i have rewrote it with my specifiec table information. check my edit 3. E.G. my table's don't use capitals just poster, or commentaar (=songcomments) and lessen_comments. Hope we could fix the fetch time :)

Comment: @linger, i did not even check the Fiddle example, this was onknow for my but thanx! I could use this for any other questions i would have. :) (probably have to register here first.. )

Comment: ... if your question doesn't list the 'correct' column names, that's your problem, not mine.  Especially as some people must anonymize their tables/columns, it's expected that askers translate answers as needed.  Also, unless you're using a specific option (which is generally advised against), SQL is actually case in-sensitive; people usually use certain casing styles to help differentiate things.  Is there something else you need?

Comment: i don't understand the query i have tried all kind of options but without the songcommentcount it takes 6 sec to load but with it takes 24 sec. What could cause this load time (this songcomment table is only 5000 rows, the songs is 10000 rows the poster is 50.000 rows. thanks already.

Comment: Too many possibilities - lack of indices, machine is insufficient, DBA stuck table in a different physical location, etc.  If you have specific performance issues, ask that as a question.