# SUM multiple columns from multiple tables with filtering

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, sum

Our users can like, save, share, and create content on both the mobile and the web. Each of those actions is represented by a table with a `source` column with values of either `mobile` or `web`.

I need to find our most active mobile users, represented by the total sum of likes, shares, saves, and creates.

```
User has_many Likes, Likes belong_to User
User has_many Shares, Shares belong_to User
User has_many Saves, Saves belong_to User
User has_many Creates, Creates belong_to User

// User Table
id | full_name | email | ...

// Likes, Share, Save, Create Table
id | user_id | source | ...
```

My ideal output would be something like:

```
// ordered by grand total
id | full_name | total likes | total saves | total creates | total shares | grand total
```

I can create a query for one of those actions:

```
SELECT u.full_name, u.id, COUNT(*) as "Likes"
FROM users u, likes l
WHERE u.id = l.user_id and l.source = 'mobile'
GROUP BY full_name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

But I'm not sure how to sum up all of their actions across the different tables.

Our `users` table has `likes_count`, `saves_count` and `create_count` fields that get updated when each of those actions is performed, but they increase with mobile and web activity, and as stated above, I just need mobile. It's also missing a count for shares, and I was hoping to include that while trying to figure out who our most active mobile users are.

I'm not sure where to start, as it seems like it'll be a pretty hairy query.

We're using Rails, so I'd be fine with a console based solution (which will dump the SQL).

Comment: Sorry, just because I'm thick, could you outline the relevant table structure a little more clearly. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielCasserly no problem at all. just updated it. let me know if you need more detail

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
SELECT username, ident, SELECT SUM(COUNT(l.id)+count(sa.id)+...)  as Total
FROM(   
  SELECT u.full_name as username, u.id as ident, COUNT(l.id) AS  likes,
       count(sa.id) as saves, ...
  FROM users u, likes l, saves sa, ...
  WHERE u.id = l.user_id and l.source = 'mobile'
  AND (u.id = sa.user_id and sa.source = 'mobile')
  ...
  GROUP BY full_name)
ORDER BY Total DESC
```

Comment: hmm, I'm not able to get that to work. seems to be failing at the `SELECT SUM(likes+saves)` part.

Comment: Ok, you may have to switch in the 'count(x.id)'s.  I'll edit ... this might mean you have to expand the 'order by Total...' to 'order by sum(count(l.id)+count(sa.id)...)'

Comment: It's not liking that second `SELECT` by the `SUM`. This won't be formatted, but this is the first query that hasn't returned an error. Unfortunately it's returning only 1 row, with what seems to be like the full sum irrespective of the GROUP BY: `SELECT username, SUM(likes+shares) as Total
FROM(   
  SELECT u.full_name as username, COUNT(l.id) AS likes, count(sh.id) as shares
  FROM users u, likes l, shares sh
  WHERE (u.id = l.user_id and l.source = 'mobile')
  AND (u.id = sh.user_id and sh.source = 'mobile')
  GROUP BY username) Activities`

Comment: hmm, not sure then.  This question/answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184444/how-to-sum-a-multiple-count-from-multiple-tables?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up with. Creating multiple virtual tables and joining them on the user's full name:

```
SELECT likes_table.full_name,
   COALESCE(likes_count,0) AS likes, 
   COALESCE(saves_count, 0) AS saves, 
   COALESCE(share_count,0) AS shares, 
   COALESCE(create_count,0) AS "create", 
   (COALESCE(likes_count,0) + COALESCE(saves_count,0) + COALESCE(share_count,0) + COALESCE(create_count,0)) AS TOTAL
FROM (
SELECT u.full_name, count(*) AS likes_count 
FROM users u, likes l
WHERE u.id = l.user_id 
AND l.source = 'mobile'
GROUP BY u.full_name) AS likes_table
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT u.full_name, COUNT(*) AS saves_count 
        FROM users u, saves s
        WHERE u.id = s.user_id
        WHERE s.source = 'mobile' 
        GROUP BY u.full_name) AS saves_table 
    ON likes_table.full_name = saves_table.full_name
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT u.full_name, COUNT(*) AS share_count
        FROM users u, shares sh
        WHERE u.id = sh.user_id
        AND sh.source = 'mobile'
        GROUP BY u.full_name) as shares_table
    ON likes_table.full_name = shares_table.full_name
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT u.full_name, COUNT(*) AS create_count
        FROM users u, create c
        WHERE u.id = c.user_id
        AND c.source = 'mobile'
        GROUP BY u.full_name) as create_table
    ON likes_table.full_name = create_table.full_name
ORDER BY TOTAL DESC
```